# Android: greenDao pattern loader

Tags: android, loader, greendao, contentobserver

I try to reload data from db when something has changed in the table. I did it using ActiveAndroid and it worked perfect.

I registered contentObserver inside AsyncTaskLoader:

```
public AsyncTaskObjectLoader(Context context, Uri observerUri) {
    this(context);
    context.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(observerUri, true, new ForceLoadContentObserver());
    onContentChanged();
}
```

where observerUri is table URI from greenDao contentProvider. It looks like:

```
"content://" + AUTHORITY + "/" + TABLENAME
```

But it gives no effect. When I insert new records into table, loader does not reload data.